# JQuery validation plugin issue with checkboxes and radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

When a validation error occurs on an input or select field the plugin adds the error class to it so in the css I can have something like:

```
.error { border: 2px solid red; }
```

but this doesn't work on checkboxes and radios due to some browsers not allowing these types of elements to be styled. So for these 2 types of elements I would like the div with the class `block` that contains them to be given the error class instead. So it will look like this on error:

```
<div class="block error">
    <input type="checkbox" name="something" class="error" /> Something
</div>
```

How can the plugin be extended to achieve this?

Pseudo code:

```
$.validator.addClassRules('checkboxOrRadioError', {
   onError: function() {
       $(this).parents('.block').addClass('error');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `errorPlacement` callback to over ride the default placement of errors or the `highlight` callback in conjunction with `unhighlight`. You now take control of what happens but must write all the conditions

Example:

```
$('form').validate(function() {

    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        var $el = $(element);
        if ($el.is(':radio') || $el.is(':checkbox')) {
            $el.closest('.block').addClass(errorClass)

        } else { 
                /* add code for default*/
        }

    },

    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) { 
                /* code to reverse the above*/
    }
})​
```

Comment: I get this error in the console: TypeError: element.is is not a function `if(element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {`

Comment: try wrap in `$()`  `$(element)`  has been a while since I worked with plugin..code in answer modified also